# how to make a string refer to the list with the same name?

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I've found a way to create new lists with this method where p is an integer variable:

```
L=""
L= "player" + str(p) + "=[]"
exec(L)
```

However I don't know how to refer back to these list using a variable.
when p=5, the list player5=[] is created. But I can't refer back to it as (playerp), since p doesn't get converted to 5 like a variable. How can I refer back to the list playerp?

```
p=10
print(player10) 
M= "player" + str(p)
print(M)
print(M is player10)

output:
[]
player10
False
```

right now M is the string "playerp", how do I make it so that M will refer to the list playerp instead of the string "playerp"(player10 in the example)?

Comment: This is a job for a list of lists, not `exec`.

Comment: Build a dictionary of players instead

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: I’d like to find whoever it is that goes around teaching new programmers about `exec()` and have them tried as a war criminal.  It’s almost always the absolute worst tool in the toolbox and inevitably causes a lot of pain for the beginner until someone rescues them.

Answer (score 0):

As it was commented using Dictionaries is a good way to create dynamic variables, here is a sample code:

```
a={}
k=0
while k<10:
    key = "player"+str(k)
    value = list(a.get("player"+str(k-1),[0]))+list([k])
    a[key] = value 
    k += 1
print (a)
```

This link might be helpful:
[How can you dynamically create variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables)

Comment: the lists I'm using are objects in a class function. Is it possible to take individual list from a dictionary and assign them to a class function?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass them to a class method? if you could provide an example, it would be so helpful.